# How to generate "ssh-rsa" key instead of "rsa-sha2-512"

Tags: linux, ssh, security

I have many servers for which I have properly generated keys, set permissions and was able to ssh/scp without password.
However there is one machine which is a little bit different and I think that I have found the difference.

The difference is that on machine for which I coulnd not connect without password is that ssh is accepting keys:

```
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 279
```

and all other my machines are accepting:

```
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg rsa-sha2-512 blen 279
```

While creating ssh keys I always set argument "-t rsa" and I'm not sure which kind of key is generated. Can you help me to create ssh-rsa key instaed of rsa-sha2-512? And last one thing - I cannot modify /etc/ssh/sshd_config to change something.

Full dump of ssh log are below:
One to which I can connect:

```
OpenSSH_7.4p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips  26 Jan 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 58: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to HOSTNAME [IP] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /SOMEPATH/SOMEDIR/SOMEFOLDER/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /SOMEPATH/SOMEDIR/SOMEFOLDER/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /SOMEPATH/SOMEDIR/SOMEFOLDER/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /SOMEPATH/SOMEDIR/SOMEFOLDER/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /SOMEPATH/SOMEDIR/SOMEFOLDER/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /SOMEPATH/SOMEDIR/SOMEFOLDER/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /SOMEPATH/SOMEDIR/SOMEFOLDER/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /SOMEPATH/SOMEDIR/SOMEFOLDER/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.4
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.4
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.4 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to HOSTNAME:22 as 'SOMEUSER'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: curve25519-sha256 need=64 dh_need=64
debug1: kex: curve25519-sha256 need=64 dh_need=64
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:###HASH###
debug1: Host 'HOSTNAME' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /SOMEPATH/SOMEDIR/SOMEFOLDER/.ssh/known_hosts:2
debug1: rekey after ###HASH### blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey after ###HASH### blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-keyex
debug1: No valid Key exchange context
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
No Kerberos credentials available (default cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_38000069)

debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
No Kerberos credentials available (default cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_38000069)

debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /SOMEPATH/SOMEDIR/SOMEFOLDER/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg rsa-sha2-512 blen 279
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to HOSTNAME ([IP]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_US.UTF-8
```

Second one to which I cannot connect:

```
OpenSSH_7.4p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips  26 Jan 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 58: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to HOSTNAME [IP] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /SOMEPATH/SOMEDIR/SOMEFOLDER/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /SOMEPATH/SOMEDIR/SOMEFOLDER/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /SOMEPATH/SOMEDIR/SOMEFOLDER/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /SOMEPATH/SOMEDIR/SOMEFOLDER/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /SOMEPATH/SOMEDIR/SOMEFOLDER/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /SOMEPATH/SOMEDIR/SOMEFOLDER/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /SOMEPATH/SOMEDIR/SOMEFOLDER/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /SOMEPATH/SOMEDIR/SOMEFOLDER/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.4
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version Sun_SSH_1.1.8
debug1: no match: Sun_SSH_1.1.8
debug1: Authenticating to HOSTNAME:22 as 'USERNAME'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-rsa
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: hmac-sha2-256 compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: hmac-sha2-256 compression: none
debug1: kex: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256 need=32 dh_need=32
debug1: kex: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256 need=32 dh_need=32
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<8192<8192) sent
debug1: got SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: got SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ssh-rsa SHA256:###HASH###
debug1: Host 'HOSTNAME' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /SOMEPATH/SOMEDIR/SOMEFOLDER/.ssh/known_hosts:13
debug1: rekey after ###HASH### blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey after ###HASH### blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-keyex
debug1: No valid Key exchange context
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
No Kerberos credentials available (default cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_38000069)

debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
No Kerberos credentials available (default cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_38000069)

debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /SOMEPATH/SOMEDIR/SOMEFOLDER/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 279
debug1: Authentications that can continue: gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Trying private key: /SOMEPATH/SOMEDIR/SOMEFOLDER/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /SOMEPATH/SOMEDIR/SOMEFOLDER/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /SOMEPATH/SOMEDIR/SOMEFOLDER/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Next authentication method: keyboard-interactive
Password:
```

Command which I'm using in order to generate key:

```
ssh-keygen -b 2048 -t rsa -E sha256 -f filename
```

I have also tried to:

- Create key with different parameters:

  -t rsa1; -t ecdsa; -b 1024; -b 2048;

Comment: What is the full command line you are using to generate your keys? Please [edit] the question to include this information.

Comment: @DavidPostill done.

Comment: Why are the servers configured differently?  One accepts `keyboard-interactive` and the other one does.  You should make the necessary changes to `sshd_config`.  Would be helpful if you provided the relevant information from `sshd_config`

Answer (score 9):

RSA keys themselves are [neither "SHA1" nor "SHA2"](https://superuser.com/questions/1556852/how-to-check-if-your-ssh-keys-are-in-the-ssh-rsa2-format/1556861#1556861) – the key format doesn't involve any hash algorithm at all. The private key just consists of two large numbers, and unlike certificates, there is no attached signature.

However, SSH did not leave much flexibility in what hash algorithm to use with each pubkey algorithm – for example, it was originally specified that whenever an "ssh-rsa" key was used for signing it would be together with SHA1 and nothing else. So in order to allow people to use their existing RSA keys, new signature algorithm names had to be created *purely for the connection handshake* – **`pkalg rsa-sha2-512` still means using the same ssh-rsa key,** only performing signatures with SHA2 instead.

Usually this feature is enabled by agreement when both the client and the server claim to support it. If you want to disable it for servers which wrongly claim support for rsa-sha2, in the OpenSSH client you can customize `PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes`:

```
ssh -o "PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes=ssh-rsa" [...]
```

But it won't help in your case because the client already correctly detects that the server doesn't support RSA with SHA2. Your problem is most likely somewhere else entirely.

Comment: Note that this is, very specifically, *not* a post about the new OpenSSH 8.8 behavior of rejecting ssh-rsa signatures; it predates that change by two years. (The original question also shows that the OpenSSH version involved was 7.4, and even demonstrates that the client was offering *and* the server was accepting an ssh-rsa signature.)

Answer (score 0):

I had similar situation.

As this is not answer how to generate key, but rather what causes sshd to reject pubkey authentication and accept only password. I thought for some of you this maybe useful.

Some firewalls - like Palo Alto, Fortigate, CheckPoint, and others - are able to work as transparent SSH proxy and intercept traffic, but they are unable to authenticate using private key.

So if you don't know, it won't hurt if you ask your admin if he's not doing anything nasty.

Here's the output with firewall enabled:

```
52:~ laimis$ ssh -v mem
OpenSSH_7.8p1, LibreSSL 2.6.2
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/laimis/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 48: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to mem port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/laimis/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: identity file /Users/laimis/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/laimis/.ssh/id_dsa type 1
debug1: identity file /Users/laimis/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/laimis/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/laimis/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/laimis/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/laimis/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/laimis/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/laimis/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.8
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version PaloAltoNetworks_0.2
debug1: no match: PaloAltoNetworks_0.2
debug1: Authenticating to mem:22 as 'laimis'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-rsa
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: hmac-sha1 compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: hmac-sha1 compression: none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(2048<7680<8192) sent
debug1: got SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: got SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ssh-rsa SHA256:S0MWqGuhCYBUQq4T9evKCHomiPHxLw/Sdda41XmAg3g
debug1: Host 'mem' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/laimis/.ssh/known_hosts:521
debug1: rekey after 4294967296 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey after 4294967296 blocks
debug1: Skipping ssh-dss key /Users/laimis/.ssh/id_dsa - not in PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: RSA SHA256:B26Tg4YaV+VsS1Ou0wcKY/jD5sBh7IWIFw19DCdZhw0 /Users/laimis/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 149
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/laimis/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/laimis/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/laimis/.ssh/id_xmss
debug1: Next authentication method: password
laimis@mem's password: 
debug1: Authentication succeeded (password).
Authenticated to mem ([10.130.10.65]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LANG = lt_LT.UTF-8
Welcome to Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.15.0-45-generic x86_64)
```

Here's the output with firewall disabled:

```
52:~ laimis$ ssh -v mem
OpenSSH_7.8p1, LibreSSL 2.6.2
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/laimis/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 48: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to mem port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/laimis/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: identity file /Users/laimis/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/laimis/.ssh/id_dsa type 1
debug1: identity file /Users/laimis/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/laimis/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/laimis/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/laimis/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/laimis/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/laimis/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/laimis/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.8
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3 pat OpenSSH_7.0*,OpenSSH_7.1*,OpenSSH_7.2*,OpenSSH_7.3*,OpenSSH_7.4*,OpenSSH_7.5*,OpenSSH_7.6*,OpenSSH_7.7* compat 0x04000002
debug1: Authenticating to mem:22 as 'laimis'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: umac-64-etm@openssh.com compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: umac-64-etm@openssh.com compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:QG8mC4gGXfD8CmWA71LTOs8yqeKhFP3Jz2pf1AYLw7s
debug1: Host 'mem' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/laimis/.ssh/known_hosts:521
debug1: rekey after 4294967296 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey after 4294967296 blocks
debug1: Skipping ssh-dss key /Users/laimis/.ssh/id_dsa - not in PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: RSA SHA256:B26Tg4YaV+VsS1Ou0wcKY/jD5sBh7IWIFw19DCdZhw0 /Users/laimis/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg rsa-sha2-512 blen 149
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to mem ([10.130.10.65]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LANG = lt_LT.UTF-8
Welcome to Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.15.0-45-generic x86_64)
```

Answer (score -1):

Try with

ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 2048 -E sha512

Comment: You should read the author's question again, the author is specifically looking to generate a SHA256 key, instead of a SHA512 key